Unity Undertone Voice Recognition Not Recognizing Speech From the Second Time Being Invoked
I am using Undertone for a Unity project to recognize user speech input and transcribe them in real time.
I largely duplicated from the RealtimeTranscriber.cs example, which is included in their demo scene and on the website. It uses a public SpeechEngine Engine and have an event public event TextTranscribed OnTextTranscribed (the brief headers are attached at the end of this post).
Another script (let me call it SpeechCheck.cs) deals with the result of the transcribed text, the transcription was achieved by having a listener and hook up the event:
RealtimeTranscriber listener

// In initialize() 
// Add a listener for when text is transcribed during initialization 
listener.OnTextTranscribed += text =>
{
    _text = text;
};

// In Update() 
listener.StartListening(); 
// This is called when the user is supposed to say something
// and the `_text` will be updated with the recognized transcription. 

Since the user is supposed to speak like in a conversation, in the scene there are several objects that has the SpeechCheck.cs attached for different handling.
When the first time SpeechCheck.cs is used and the listener is started, everything works fine, _text got updated and the recognition is fairly accurate. However, after the first object with SpeechCheck.cs is disabled, the second object with SpeechCheck.cs component does not work, _text remains to be nothing.
To ensure it's not some parameters that failed to get reset, I even tried to create new components and assign them during run time, so that everything should be new:
// Still in SpeechCheck.cs
// In initialize() 
Engine = this.AddComponent<SpeechEngine>(); 

this.AddComponent<SpeechListener>();
GetComponent<SpeechListener>().Engine = Engine; 

listener = this.GetComponent<SpeechListener>();

// In Update(), after everything is done and this component is no longer needed
listener.StopListening();
Destroy(GetComponent<SpeechListener>());
Destroy(GetComponent<SpeechEngine>());

And was of no avail, the listener still only works for the first time's call.
What may have caused this problem?
Since their website does not show the code, attached is the method headers:
public class RealtimeTranscriber : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SpeechEngine Engine;
    public event TextTranscribed OnTextTranscribed;
    //... 

    private void Start();
    public bool VADTriggered (float[] samples);
    private IEnumerator TranscribeCoroutine();
    public void StartListening();
    public void StopListening();
    private async Task TranscribeAudioClipAsync(float[] samples, bool flush);
    private void RecalculateWindowSize();
    private void OnDestroy();

}


are you sure that the `listener.OnTextTranscribed += text =>
{
_text = text;
};
// In Update()
listener.StartListening(); ` code is getting reset when new call is made?

Yes ... one can't really tell if your starts and stops match; and whether or not you're hooking your eventhandler(s) more than once.

@BugFinder Well, the thing is each invoke is theoretically independent. Like, GameObject A will create its own RealtimeTranscriber_A in runtime and retrieve transcription from this transcriber A only. After the use transcriber A is destroyed and GameObject A is disabled. Then GameObject B will also create its own  RealtimeTranscriber_B so on and so forth. So reset or not, the text should not interfere with each other

@GerrySchmitz I understand. This thing has quite a lot of parts and it's really hard to describe their relationships. Even if I managed to remove all the redundancies and upload it as a Unity project, I am not sure if people are willing to download and run it...

Some things only make sense as "singletons". Voice recognition would be one. If you keep having to "re-instantiate" in this case, that's not helping.
